# Server 2008 R2, Exchange 2010, WMI error event 10

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, windows-event-log, wmi

### The system is windows 2008 R2, with Exchange 2010 SP1 installed.

I am receiving the following event log application error:

---

event 10, WMI

> ```
> Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent
> ```
>
> WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA
>   "Win32_Processor" AND
>   TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99"
>   could not be reactivated in namespace
>   "//./root/CIMV2" because of error
>   0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered
>   through this filter until the problem
>   is corrected.

---

I am having a hard time solving this error, and figuring out exactly what problem this error may cause

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This KB article seems to be the answer to your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950375

Answer (score 2):

Good place to [start](http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=10&source=WMI).

Comment: yes i have researched it and read a lot about it - but everything i was reading was for vista mostly - SO i wasn't sure if it was the same scenario for a server with exchange. thanks

Comment: I assume you have downloaded and installed all the updates and fixes from Microsoft Update?

Comment: yes - everything is updated and current

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:[Event ID 10 is logged in the Application log after you install Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows 2008, Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950375)